# Trying to sum cells depending on text at the top of a column and beginning of a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a budget template in Excel that can be easily expanded without needing to update formulas to include new additions. On the summary sheet of the workbook, I have two columns for each month, one titled "Estimate" and one titled "Actual". I have row titles in the first column like "Rent", "Payroll", "Total Expenses", etc.

I have two columns at the end of the sheet for annual totals. I have the "Estimate" and "Year-to-Date" titles. Each row in these columns sums the "Estimate" values across the row, and the "Actual" values across the row, respectively. Here's where I'm having trouble: I want to be able to add new months with "Estimate" and "Actual" columns before the last two summary columns at the end of the sheet, without having to update the =SUM formulas in the last columns to include the two new columns. I was thinking if I could create a =SUMIF kind of formula where it looks for cells where the top of the column says "Estimate" and the start of the row says "Rent" (for example), it sums all those values that have those 'coordinates'. But I don't know how to make that work.

If you have an idea of a better solution to what I'm trying to do I'd gladly take it! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: An alternate solution is using a pivot table, it will require a change in your data table, for example inserting a column for your months/year.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a marker column after your actual data. Then you add new columns **before** this marker. In formulas addresses should include this marker column however it is empty. Formulas will be updated correctly after adding new columns.
[image: Budget]

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you!!